# Evaluate multiple values from same input field using dynamic ids

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the following data item

```
dataItem = [
    0: {
        "item1" : "someData",
        "item2" : "someData",
        "id" : "1234-fg43-22f3-2323",
        "count" : 12
        },
    1: {
        "item1" : "someData",
        "item2" : "someData",
        "id" : "fg34-rt43-2fgd-29kj",
        "count" : 13
        }   
]
```

HTML

```
<div ng-if="dataItem.length > 1" ng-repeat="items in dataItem">
<table>
    <tr>
    Need to get values
    <tr>
    <td>
        <input type="text" ng-value="items.count" id="{{items.id}}" />
    </td>
</table>
```

I am using the `id` to get the value the following way

```
dataItem.forEach((val, key) => {
    //var itemArray = [];
    //if (document.getElementById(val.id)) {
    //    itemArray.push(document.getElementById(val.id).value);
    //}

    var countHereIs = document.getElementById(val.id).value;
    if (countHereIs == val.count) {
        swal("similar");
    }
    if (countHereIs != val.count) {
        noErrors = false;
        swal("not same");
    }
});
```

I am able to get the values successfully but I want to check them in a if condition to see if values entered are the same or not. I have not been able to evaluate properly as if I enter incorrect data, I get `similar` as result.

I tried to use an array approach but that results in individual array. How can I check the values individually against `val.count`

Comment: someone help, I have been at it for a quite a while with no solution. Any guidance where I am going wrong will help. Thanks.

Comment: Do you want to check if the user entered value, is same for `count` variable in at least one object from the `dataItem` array?

Comment: @Harshad, I want to evaluate both. if id is `1234-fg43-22f3-2323` then the count should be 12, similarly, for the other id, the count should be 13. And yes, the input comes from the user

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used a while loop to finish this. Looking for more solutions

```
var i = 0;
while (i < dataItem.length) {
    var itemCount= document.getElementById(dataItem[i].id).value;
    if (itemCount !== (dataItem[i].count).toString()) {
        noErrors = false;
        swal("not same");
    }
    i++;
}
```